# Rails 4 find_or_create_by with accepts_nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, belongs-to

I have the following models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo
end
```

Bar contains 'object' and Foo contains 'label'.

I can do the following:

```
f=Foo.create(:label=>"label",:bar_attributes=>{:object=>"mason jar"})
```

This works fine.

However, what I *WANT* to do is:

```
f=Foo.find_or_create_by(:label=>"label",:bar_attributes=>{:object=>"mason jar"})
```

The problem is, this fails with a SQL error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: bar_attributes.object: SELECT  "foo".* FROM "foo" WHERE "foo"."label" = ? AND "bar_attributes"."object" = 'mason jar' LIMIT 1
```

I can understand why this is happening, but I want to be able to use that functionality.  I know that I need to add code to do the "find_or_create_by" for Bar, but I have this working already, so I'm not putting that here, only the problem that I am currently having.

So, is there a way to make the 'find' for Foo just IGNORE bar_attributes, and only use it when it is necessary (for the create)?

Or, is there another way to accomplish this?

EDIT:  Explaining why this is the way it is:

We have two separate objects.  Bar is a standalone object.  Foo is a separate object type which contains a Bar.

So, we could have several records in Bar:

```
Mason jar
Shovel
Can of corn
```

And we could have other records in Foo:

```
label: 123 => Bar: Shovel
label: 456 => Bar: Shovel
label: 123 => Bar: Can of corn
```

All Bar's in Foo are valid Bar's, but only Bar's with labels in Foo are a Foo.

So, basically, I want to be able to run:

```
f = Foo.find_or_create_by(:label=>'label',:bar_attributes=>{:object='object'})
```

and have it create the Bar if necessary, then create the Foo if necessary.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You can chain find_or_create_by with :where, or any custom scope. Have you tried use a where clause before use `find_or_create_by` ?

Comment: Well, in general, nested attributes once was a gem, which later was incorporated into Rails, so whatever applies to ActiveRecord does not have to work with nested attributes. Are you trying to create a Foo object only in case if Bar object with some attributes does not exist?

Comment: Not all of the code is above.  In a nutshell, what I want to do is run a find_or_create_by on Bar, and then use the result for the find_or_create_by on Foo.

Comment: Then I guess you should do find on Bar first, then if needed to create it, and then finally create Foo. It is a straight-forward way. In order to suggest something more suitable, one have to understand what you are doing actually. For example, maybe :reject_if for nested_attributes can work for you.

Comment: Added more information to original post.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can do it like this:

```
f = Foo.find_or_create_by(label: 'label', bar: Bar.find_or_create_by(object: 'object'))
```

It is equivalent to

f = Foo.find_or_create_by(label: 'label', bar_id: Bar.find_or_create_by(object: 'object').id)

You might want to make it two lines in order to check that Bar was created (without validation failures).